# Cannot slice a datetime index like a tutorial example does

Tags: python, pandas

Referring to this '[data wrangling](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_time_series_basics/)' tutorial they give examples like:

```
#View all observations that occured in 2014
df['2014']
#View all observations that occured in May 2014
df['2014-05']
```

But when I try these, I get `KeyError` exceptions on my Python 3.6 notebook.

I don't see anything funny about my DataFrame, different from the examples:

```
df = pd.read_excel(fn, "tb")
df.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)
print(type(df.index))
print(type(df.index[0]))
```

yields:

```
<class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
Out[33]:
    foo bar baz zah
Date                
2010-01-04 00:00:00 8.14    78.29   9.21    6.01
2010-01-05 00:00:00 8.81    79.74   10.14   6.15
2010-01-06 00:00:00 8.91    79.80   10.51   5.70
```

my error occurs even with:

```
df['2010']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index is not a [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). Try:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Then you will be able to use all of [pandas awesome datetime functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using one of the following two way

`import datetime
   df = datetime.datetime.now()
   print(df.year)
   print(df.strftime('%Y'))`